# Homepage not loading correctly, but then loads when refreshing

Tags: wp-enqueue-style, css

When going to our homepage (www.whiteskitchen.co.uk). We seem to have lost the styling on the homepage. I checked the source code and it’s not fully loading the page.

When you refresh the page or click on a link, the page reverts to the correct theme styling and loads correctly. The stylings are very different and you’ll notice the difference

Any ideas what it could be? It only started happening a couple of days ago and no updates or changes have been made before or after the issue cropped up

The site I need help with is http://www.whiteskitchen.co.uk.

Comment: Problems witch cache. Check your theme and cache plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that there is a problem with the cache. Try clearing the cache with plugins, like [WP Super Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/). Follow these steps:

1. Install and activate WP Super Cache.
2. Head to **Settings > WP Super Cache**.
3. Click on **Delete Cache** button under **Delete Cached Pages**.

It should fix your issue. However, if you are still experiencing the styling problem in your homepage, there must be an issue with the theme.

Comment: Thanks dado and Ehsanul Haque. I used W3 to delete the cache, but that didn't seem to work. Ended up contacting my host, whom cleared the Cache on their side, and seems to be working now. Didn't get round to trying the WP Super Cache method. But sure it works as well